# Anchor <a> tag not working between <p> tag

Tags: html, anchor

I'm new in HTML language. Currently im learning from Youtube, Google. Im using windows 10 OS and Chrome browser as well as Mozila. I'm using ATOM texteditor to write code. I have created simple page. And wanted to use Anchor tag  to generate link. However it not getting. I tried many methods found on similar topic. But none of them worked. Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Orbital Dispatch </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>Orbital Dispatch</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the site</p>
    <hr ="5">
    <a href="orbitalsystems.html"></a>Orbital Systems Bombay Pvt Ltd
    <p><a href="orbitalmekatronik.html"></a>Orbital Mekatronik Systems Pvt Ltd</p>




  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put text between `<a></a>` tags for the blue link text to appear. your text is currently in the `<p></p>` tags, and the `<a></a>` tags contain nothing. You don't need a `<p>` if you're using `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Put your text between the opening and closing tags like I did in the example and the path that you define in href attribute should be correct, let's assume your file is inside the pages folder so it will be like this.

```
href="pages/about.html"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Orbital Dispatch </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>Orbital Dispatch</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the site</p>
    <hr ="5">
    <a href="orbitalsystems.html">Orbital Systems Bombay Pvt Ltd</a>
    <p><a href="orbitalmekatronik.html">Orbital Mekatronik Systems Pvt Ltd</a></p>




  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the text outside the anchor tag. Use This `<a href='orbitalsystems.html'>Orbital Systems Bombay Pvt Ltd </a>`

Answer (score 0):

**You should always enclose the content between the opening & closing tags,** the Anchor tag should be like:

```
<a herf="orbitalsystems.html">Orbital Systems Bombay Pvt Ltd</a>
```

And also there should not be a empty attribute in any element.(<hr ="5">)
Need to be corrected as `<hr aAttribute="5">`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Orbital Dispatch </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>Orbital Dispatch</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the site</p>
    <hr width="500px">
    <a href="orbitalsystems.html">Orbital Systems Bombay Pvt Ltd</a>
    <p><a href="orbitalmekatronik.html">Orbital Mekatronik Systems</a> Pvt Ltd</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try Considering This One This Probably Might Help You

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Orbital Dispatch </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>Orbital Dispatch</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the site</p>
    <hr ="5">
    <a href="orbitalsystems.html">Orbital Systems Bombay Pvt Ltd</a>
    <p><a href="orbitalmekatronik.html">Orbital Mekatronik Systems Pvt Ltd</p></a>
  </body>
</html>
```